# How can I show one collapsible item in twitter bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Dear friends and programmers.

The following is a part of my code. Its, actually, a part of my side menu. My problem with the code is a common problem many Bootstrap users run into. I want only one of my collapsible items to be shown once it is clicked on, and the other previously opened one get closed.
Thanks in advance.

```html
<ul>
    <li class="link">
        <a href="index.php">
            <span class="fas fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Home</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="link">
        <a href="#collapse-post"  data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-post">
            <span class="fas fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Operation</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="collapse collapse-li-border" id="collapse-post">
            <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Create</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>


    <li class="link">
        <a href="#collapse-edari"  data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-edari">
            <span class="fas fa-bullseye" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span>Office</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="collapse collapse-li-border" id="collapse-edari">
            <li><a href="#">Word</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Access</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Powerpoint</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi. Inlcude also your css please, so we can have something to work on.

Comment: Hi Ludovit, the main css framework is bootstrap 4. Do I need to send anything else?

Comment: Read the docs and [use the Collapse accordion](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#accordion-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. in your example you should follow more carefully documentation for [dropdown component of bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/). Collapse component is not exactly used in these cases. I made some changes in your code, but you need to tweak it for your specific case.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul>
    <li class="link">
        <a href="index.php">
            <span class="fas fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span>Home</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="link">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
            <span class="fas fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span>Operation</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="collapse-post">
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Create</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>


    <li class="link">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
            <span class="fas fa-bullseye" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span>Office</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="collapse-edari">
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Word</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Access</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Powerpoint</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```